# Is it impossible to fully pave this imaginary bathroom with some conditions?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, packing-problem

Bob and Sarah decide to pave their bathroom floor with ceramic tiles. The bathroom measures $1.4$m by $3.7$m. A tile is a square slab with side length $30$cm. Tiles not closest to the walls of the bathroom must be whole (i.e. not cut into). Only tiles closest to the walls can be rectangular slabs that were made from a $30\times30$ tile, that was cut along a straight edge (by the manufacturer) no more than once. What is the least number of tiles the manufacturer must make in order for the bathroom floor to be fully paved?

I have tried a few cases by keep getting problems around the edges/corners of the room. Am I correct in thinking that such an arrangement of tiles is impossible, and if so, how to formalise this?

Basically we have $10$cm left over on the $3.7$m side, and $20$cm left over on the $1.4$m side, but this leaves open a lot of possibilities...

In reality the corners would not be a problem and the manufacturer would cut some (either $1, 2$ or $4$) of the tiles twice, so I guess this problem is more of a hypothetical one.

Comment: "In reality" the corners would not be a problem even with the limitation that the manufacturer can only cut the tiles once, since they could cut them diagonally and make two small triangular pieces to fill in the final corner

Comment: It is impossible. cover bathroom floor by an axes-aligned square grid of spacing $15$cm. Painting the squares (or rectangles at boundaries) by black/white paint in a chessboard pattern.You can position the grid so that the average color of the whole floor is not 50% gray. However, for any tile obtainable from a $30\times 30$ tile with at most one cut, when is is placed on the floor axes-aligned with the floor, the average color of the area it cover is always 50% gray!

Comment: @achillehui: There will always be a rectangle in your grid at one of the corners whose width and height are both less than 15cm. So I don't think your last sentence is true for tiles that cover this rectangle.

Comment: @TonyK, it still works. Let's say a horizontal $320\times h$ tile cover that rectangle. Cut it into two $160 x h$ tile, you will notice the tile at left has same pattern as that at right with black/white reversed.

Comment: @achillehui: Yes, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @achillehui - Love your coloring argument.  If I understand correctly, it works because the tile is $30 \times 30$ and both edges are even multiples of $15$.  What if the tile is e.g. $30 \times 10 \pi$?  Or more generally what if the two sides of the room and the two sides of the tile are four independent (is that the right term?) irrational numbers?  It would be very surprising if a tiling is possible, and yet I cannot think of a way to generalize your coloring argument.

Comment: @achillehui - I have made my $30 \times 10 \pi$ version into a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4117470/tiling-a-room-when-room-and-or-tile-dimensions-are-irrational).  Any insights would be most welcome!

Comment: @ achille hui or anyone else - Please feel free to post an answer.