# Tiling a room when (room and/or tile) dimensions are irrational

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, puzzle, tiling, packing-problem

My question is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109549/is-it-impossible-to-fully-pave-this-imaginary-bathroom-with-some-conditions).

There is a rectangular room of dimension $a \times b$, and there is an unlimited number of rectangular tiles of dimension $c \times d$.  You are allowed one cut on each tile, but the cut must be parallel to the edges.  So you basically have tiles of dimension $c \times y$ where $y \le d$, and dimension $x \times d$ where $x \le c$.

The question is whether you can tile the room with such tiles.  (Note: you are allowed to rotate tiles by $90$ degrees.)

In the original question, $a = 140, b = 370, c = d = 30$ and @achillehui came up with a nice coloring argument (see comment to main post) where the room is colored in a checkerboard pattern of $15 \times 15$ squares.  So each (cut or uncut) tile covers equal areas of white and black, while the room can be colored in such a way that it's not half-and-half, thereby proving the tiling is impossible.

My question: AFAICT, the coloring argument depends on $c, d$ both being *even* multiples of the same number $15$ (which can happen iff $\frac{c}{d}$ is rational).  What if this is not the case?  E.g. what if $c = 30, d = 10 \pi$?  Intuitively it still seems impossible to tile the room, but I cannot generalize the coloring argument (nor come up with a different proof).

What I seek:

- Ideally, a general criterion for when tiling is possible (as a function of $a,b,c,d$)

  - Partial result: note that rotating does help, e.g. if either room side $= m c + n d$ for non-negative integers $m,n$ then tiling is possible (regardless of the other room side).  In fact I wouldn't be surprised if this turns out to be the necessary-and-sufficient condition.
- Failing that, a proof whether my example above (where $a,b,c,d = 140, 370, 30, 10\pi$) can be tiled or not.
- Failing that, any (non-trivial) result using a different example where $a, b$ are rational and $\frac{c}{d}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use essentially the same as the second proof on [this site](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/rectangles/) where it is used to prove

> If a finite number of rectangles, every one of which has at least one integer side, perfectly tile a big rectangle, then the big rectangle also has at least one integer side.

The first proof there is the checkerboard colouring one.

I have changed the second proof slightly to show that in this problem at least one side $a$ or $b$ must be a linear combination of $c$ and $d$.

**Proof:**
Suppose you have tiled the $a\times b$ rectangle.

Construct a graph where the vertices are the points where corners of the tiles lie, and two vertices are connected if there is a tile with corners at those two vertices and the side between them is of length $c$ or length $d$. Note that if you use an uncut tile, treat it as if it were cut along one of its dimensions. In this way every tile contributes exactly two edges to the graph, incrementing the degree of all four vertices.

The vertices at the corners of the large rectangle have degree 1, but all other vertices have degree 2 or 4 because at each vertex there are either two or four tile corners coming together, because there are exactly two or four 90-degree corners at those points.

You now walk along this graph, starting at one corner of the rectangle. Never use any edge twice. Eventually you will have to end on an odd degree vertex, which must be one of the other corners of the large rectangle.

The start and end vertex lie a distance of $a$ or $b$ apart along one of the axes, but all the steps you took along that same axis were of length $c$ or $d$. Therefore $a$ or $b$ (or even both) must be some linear combination of $c$ and $d$.

This proves that your example of $(a,b,c,d)=(140,370,30,10\pi)$ is not possible.

Note that the linear combination $mc+nd$ might use negative $m$ or $n$. As an example of this, you can take two $c\times (c-d)$ tiles, two $c\times x$ tiles, surrounding one $(c-x)\times d$ tile, to form a $(2c-d)\times(c+x)$ rectangle. (This assumes w.l.o.g. $c\ge d$, and $x$ is any value $x\le d$.)

Comment: What about the uncut $c \times d$ tile?  Wouldn't that potentially lead to degree $3$ vertex?  Reading the linked website more carefully, it seems if a tile has all four sides being special, one has to choose (arbitrarily?) to declare only one pair will be connected...?  But even then it seems it would be possible to construct degree $3$ cases...

Comment: @antkam I forgot to mention that special case, but you can choose arbitrarily for each $c\times d$ whether to treat it as one type or the other when you are constructing the graph. There won't be any degree 3 cases because every tile contributes two edges, incrementing the degree of all four vertices at its corners, and at every vertex you either get two or four 90-degree corners (except for the corners of the large rectangle).

Comment: Oh!  I was confused because I thought connections can be "merged" if they have same two corners!  If they are not merged (as your referenced website clearly says) then yes, this argument is valid.  Thanks!

Comment: It is at least sometimes possible to tile when the room edges are linear combinations using negative coefficients. For the example $a=11,b=6,c=5,d=4$ ($a=4d-c, b=2c-d$), put one uncut tile in the center with $c$ edge parallel the $a$ edge, put $6$ other tiles around it with $c$ edge parallel the $b$ edge, and cut the outer $6$ tiles to the $a \times b$ rectangle.

Comment: The problem with uncut tiles also confused me when reading the proof. I suggest editing in that step.

Comment: @aschepler I updated my answer. I also added a smaller general example of a tiling with a linear combination with negative coefficient.

Comment: Thanks to both.  This goes 90% of the way to answering my questions.  I will wait a few days before accepting this answer, just in case someone can really find the "iff" condition. I doubt that will happen.  :)